# Considering ES for following use case

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm still wrapping my head around ES and I am not 100% sure whether it is is good fit for my use case (so far everything is leaning to positive answer).

I am expecting to have ~1M entries per day stored in MySql and I was planning to prepare data and sync it to ES in JSON format below.

What I am unsure about is how well ES will respond on filtering on at least one (quite often multiple) field marked as Comparable and for the remaining fields I want to be able to do aggregation on one (and multiple) while still performing fast in combination of each.

Also I would like to be able to fetch and aggregate data up to one year

```
{
   "id_non_unique":"String"   (Comparable),
   "key_1":"Long"   (Comparable),
   "key_2":"String"   (Comparable),
   "key_3":"String"   (Comparable),
   "key_4":"String"   (Comparable),
   "key_5":"String"   (Comparable),
   "key_6":"String",
   "key_7":"String",
   "key_8":"String",
   "key_9":"String",
   "key_10":"String",
   "key_11":"String",
   "timestamp":"Instant"   (Comparable)
}
```

Comment: That's pretty much what ES excels at. If you have a sample document and a sample query, it's easy to confirm that.

Comment: What do you mean specifically by _how well ES will respond_? Are you talking about query response time efficiency? Do you have unlimited resources (CPU, memory, network, disk...)? Do you need precision on the aggregations? What kind of aggregations?